# (42000, [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near s. (102) (SQLExecDirectW))

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am programing the following sql code in python but no idea what is wrong or why I see this error:

```
query='''
    SELECT 
        FIN AS 'LIN', 
        CUSIP, 
        Borrower_Name, 
        Alias,
        DS_Maturity, 
        Spread, 
        Facility, 
        Facility_Size, 
        Log_date
    FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
    WHERE 
        CUSIP IN ('{}') 
        OR (
            YEAR(DS_Maturity) IN ('{}') 
            AND (
                Borrower_Name IN ('{}') 
                OR Alias IN ('{}')
            )
        )
'''
```

Comment: The query you posted here will parse just fine. Assuming you shortened the list of values to {} for brevity.?

Comment: Probably need some escape characters in there for those single quotes.

Comment: There is no `s.` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try like This:

```
query='''
    SELECT 
        FIN AS ''LIN'', 
        CUSIP, 
        Borrower_Name, 
        Alias,
        DS_Maturity, 
        Spread, 
        Facility, 
        Facility_Size, 
        Log_date
    FROM [Main].[FacilityInformation]
    WHERE 
        CUSIP IN ('{}') 
        OR (
            YEAR(DS_Maturity) IN ('{}') 
            AND (
                Borrower_Name IN ('{}') 
                OR Alias IN ('{}')
            )
        )
'''
```